# Is co-variance safe here?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, covariance

```
class Food{}

class Meat extends Food{}

class Animal{
    void feed(Food f){}
}

class Lion extends Animal{
    void feed(Meat m){}
}


void foo(Animal a){
   Food f = new Food();
   a.feed(f);
}
```

What will happen if we send to `foo(new Lion())` ?
I know that it will get error but I need the explanation please

Comment: Why do you think you will get an error here? Lion's feed method doesn't overrides Animal's feed method, so animal's feed method will call in foo. Overriding will occur if you try to use subclass in return type, but not in paarmeters list

Comment: Actually you won't get an error.  The Lion will eat the food, but the method in `Animal` will get called, not the more specific but non-matching method in `Lion`

Answer (score 5):

Your `Lion` can eat `Meat`, but it can also eat any kind of food (like Spinach).

If your `Lion` could not eat any kind of `Food`, then it could not be considered an implementation of `Animal`.

This is critical to understand when deciding to use sub-classing and class inheritance as a means of constructing programs: you don't make your subclasses more specific than your interface or super classes.

For sub-classing to work in ways that solve problems (instead of create problems), you need to abide by this guideline: [`All subclasses must be functionally equivalent to the super-class (Liskov Substitution Principle)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)  This means that three classes which provide database access to three different databases is a good candidate for being subclasses from a common class (or perhaps sharing a common interface), because the "functionality" is "offer database access".

Where your `Lion` example falls short is that according to your definition of `Animal` a real world, Lions are not an `Animal`s because real world Lions don't eat any kind of `Food`.  Real world Lions are more specific in their food eating ability than the general definition of an unknown animal.  And it is this functional difference which makes modeling real world Lions as subclasses of *this specific definition of Animal* a bad fit.

You could easily fix this by having the `Animal` "eat food" method throw an `IncompatibleFoodException`, which changes the definition of an `Animal` from something that "eats food" to something that "eats or rejects food".

Comment: This is where the `@Override` annotation comes in handy, because it would show that `Lion.feed(Meat)` doesn't override anything.

Answer (score 2):

This violates the [Liskov substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) principle, so it should likely be avoided (as Edwin says, it's really not an Animal if it can't eat Food).

Perhaps against first thought, this will actually not result in an error, but rather will call Animal::feed instead of Lion::feed as expected.

Just reread the title, and to answer the question specifically: No, covariance is not safe here (in terms of behaviour.  In terms of syntax it is.).

Quick copy and paste of the question into an example:

```
class Food{}

class Meat extends Food{}

class Animal{
    void feed(Food f){
        System.out.println("om nom nom");
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal{
    void feed(Meat m)
    {
        System.out.println("OM NOM NOM");
    }
}

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        foo(new Lion());
    }

    static void foo(Animal a){
       Food f = new Food();
       a.feed(f);
    }

}
```

Outputs "om nom nom"