# Why can't paintComponent accept a Graphics2D object?

Tags: java, swing, api, awt, paintcomponent

```
public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D gd2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,Color.blue,150,150,Color.red);


    }
}
```

Why is this valid but not this:

```
public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g){

        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,Color.blue,150,150,Color.red);

        g.setPaint(gradient);
        g.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }
}
```

First one renders, but the second one renders no graphics other than the frame. I noticed that paintComponent() requires a Graphics object, but if Graphics2D is a subclass of the Graphics object why can I not call a subclass of Graphics?

Is there some concept I am not picking up as to why this is?

Comment: The short answer is because it is more specific than a Graphics and thus is not a valid override of the method.  It can be equally or less specific, but not more specific.

Comment: It's not a valid override of paintComponent which JPanel has specified as (Graphics g) on it's method?

Comment: There was actually a question that talked about this in depth recently.  Look through the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950538/567864.  It should explain why you can be equally or less specific but not more specific when overriding a method.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, wish you put this as an answer, that link pretty much answers it for me. Thank you. ;-)

Comment: I went ahead and wrote it as an answer along with a little explanation that's specific to your case.  Also, as far as I know, it's always safe to cast the Graphics instance to a Graphics2D inside of a Swing component.  It is because of the inheritance tree (and historical reasons) that it must accept a Graphics and not Graphics2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you override a method, you can be equally or less specific.

Think about this:

```
JPanel p = new MyPanel();
p.paintComponent(someGraphicsInstance);
```

A reference to a `JPanel` is expected to be able to accept a Graphics reference as a parameter to the `paintComponent` method.  Your method, however, violates that requirement as it will not accept a `Graphics` instance, but only a `Graphics2D`.

More information about this can be found https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950538/567864

Answer (score 2):

It says that you should implement it this way, because Graphics2D is Graphics, while Graphics is not Graphics2D.

If you find casting disturbing, you can always create your own eg. MyJPanel that extends JPanel, define your own method, and subclass it in the future, overriding your defined method.

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        paintComponent((Graphics2D) g);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is because it's defined that way by JPanel?

Comment: Yeah, when you define your method as you are doing it now - with Graphics2D, you are simply overloading it, but it is not being called by your JPanel.

Comment: Thank you, this along with the person cleared the concept up a bit more for me. As always, you guys rock here. :-D